# Compare two arrays and filter them javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, array.prototype.map

Basically i have two arrays which i am using it for the configuration of buttons.

First array which defines how many buttons should be present and in order.

```
buttonGroups: [ 0, 2 ]
```

Another array of objects which says about the actual buttons.

```
    buttons = [
    {
        buttonLabel: 'label1',
        cond1: true,
        cond2: false
    },
    {
        buttonLabel: 'label2',
        cond1: true,
        cond2: false
    },
    {
        buttonLabel: 'label3',
        cond1: false,
        cond2: true
    }
];
```

The `buttonGroups` is the configuration array. If it has only `[0, 1]` then first two buttons will exist. If `buttonGroups` has only `[0, 3]` we should have first and third button exists in `buttons` array.

This is what i have tried

```
buttonGroups.map((payload1, index1) => {
    buttons .map((payload2, index2) => {
        if(index1 === index2){
            //Display Here only the matched index from ButtonGroups
            console.log(payload2)
        }
    })
})
```

This is giving the first index button array. How to get the matched array buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var buttonGroups = [ 0, 2 ];


var buttons = [
  {
    buttonLabel: 'label1',
    cond1: true,
    cond2: false
  },
  {
    buttonLabel: 'label2',
    cond1: true,
    cond2: false
  },
  {
    buttonLabel: 'label3',
    cond1: false,
    cond2: true
  }
];

var filteredButtons = buttonGroups.map(item => {
  return buttons[item];
});

console.log(filteredButtons);
```

`filteredButtons` will return the filtered buttons which you can render.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `buttonGroups` and get result:

```
buttonGroups.map(button => {return buttons[button]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` method.

```
const filterBtn = buttons.filter((btn,index) => buttonGroups.includes(index));
```

Comment: That would be in the wrong order. buttonGroups also indicates the order of the buttons, try your code with buttonGroups being [3,1]. The solution is much simpler and is: `buttonGroups.map((i) => buttons[i])`